# How can I crop a section of the video screen in Premiere Pro?

Tags: video, premiere

Hi I've taken a 1080p screen recording on my desktop but only want a specific crop of the actual recorded screen in the final video. How can I do this in Premiere Pro CS4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use an effect that's called a 4 point garbage matte.  It allows you to set 4 points which create a box and everything outside it is removed.
Here is a link to a tutorial on how to use the effect 4 point garbage matte.

Comment: how do I get rid of the black border?

Comment: If you make a sequence that is smaller, say 720x480 (sd) then the original, then  you can scale down your original capture to fit with no black border.